# Download file generated by JavScript without confirmation using Firefox Linux plus Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, ubuntu, firefox

I am using the Selenium web browser automatize on Firefox v90 64 bits with Geckodriver v0.29.1 at Ubuntu 20.04.

I want to automatic download some XLSX file from a webpage without Firefox ask me for confirmation. I tried the [Selenium tutorial](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html?highlight=download#how-to-auto-save-files-using-custom-firefox-profile) and other answers here on Stackoverflow but no one give me the expected result.

Above my profile definition:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opts = Options()

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', MY_PATH)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',
                       'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                       ';application/vnd.ms-excel'
                       ';application/xls'
                       ';application/xlsx')


browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile, options=opts, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
browser.get('https://filesamples.com/formats/xlsx')
btn = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('btn-primary')
btn[0].click()
```

I also checked the MIME type by the bellow code and appear right configuraded:

```py
import requests
requests.head('https://filesamples.com/samples/document/xlsx/sample3.xlsx').headers['content-type']
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```

This code works fine in the used above site. The problem is when I use in my company website where the file is generated through a JavaScript action (the click action generate a process windows, at the end the file is asked to be saved).

```html
<a id="executarAnaliseForm:accordionAnalise:_btnExportarXlsxCustom" href="#" title="Excel" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(beforeExport, afterExport);','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'executarAnaliseForm\'),{\'executarAnaliseForm:accordionAnalise:_btnExportarXlsxCustom\':\'executarAnaliseForm:accordionAnalise:_btnExportarXlsxCustom\'},\'\')');return false">
```

[image]

[image]

How to configure Selenium to make Firefox respect the `profile` in this case?

Comment: I could by pass the dialog by using the general `application/octet-stream` second https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types. But the doubt still, appear that initially the file is another MIME type, and it not respecting the download folder configured.

Comment: Can you try this - ("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/csv, text/csv, text/plain,application/octet-stream doc xls xlsx pdf txt");